# How can we show that $\int_Y gd\nu=\int_X (g\circ f) d\mu $

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $(X, \Sigma_X , \mu)$ is a measure space and let $\Sigma_Y$ be a $\sigma$-algebra on  a set $Y$. Suppose $f:X\to Y$ is a map such that $f^{-1}(A)\in \Sigma_X$ for all $A\in \Sigma_Y$. Define a set function $\nu$ on $\Sigma_Y$ by $\nu(A)=\mu(f^{-1}(A))$. Clearly $\nu$ is a measure on $\Sigma_Y$. Moreover if $g$ is a nonnegative $\Sigma_Y$-measurable function on Y, clearly $g\circ f$ is $\Sigma_X$-measurable.

My question: How can we show that $\int_Y gd\nu=\int_X (g\circ f) d\mu $? Thanks!

Comment: Show it for simple $g$ and then extend to the more general case.

Comment: Could you explain it more? Is g arbitrary simple function?

Comment: Yes, show it for an arbitrary simple, non-negative function $g$. That is, a $g$ of the form $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i\mathbf{1}_{A_i}$ for arbitrary $a_1,\ldots,a_n\geq 0$ and $A_1,\ldots,A_n\in \Sigma_Y$.

Comment: Ok I see, then what should I use to extend to any nonnegative measurable funtion g?Thanks!

Comment: "then what should I use to extend to any nonnegative measurable funtion" Surely there are theorems in your notes doing exactly that, no?

Comment: Ok there is a monotone increasing sequence of nonnegative simple functions $\phi_n$ which converges to $g$. Similarly $\phi_n \circ f \nearrow g \circ f$ . And we apply monotone converges theorem

Comment: Yes @ErginSuer. And for a general measurable $g$, you decompose $g$ into its positive and negative part, i.e. $g=g^+-g^-$.

Comment: @ErginSuer Hi how can we verify that $\phi_n \circ f \to g \circ f$? I think this need $\phi_n$ to be continuous right?